# 2001 GTI not going into reverse, 1st, 3rd, or 5th after clutch replacement

Tags: transmission, clutch, vw, gti

I changed my clutch a few days ago and now it will not engage reverse, 1st, 3rd, or 5th gear but will engage 2nd and 4th with the car on and off. I readjusted the cables but still nothing. What could this be?

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with your gear linkage. Either part of the fore-aft linkage is broken, or it's not connected properly.

Answer (score 2):

If it's similar to the Polo, having gear linkage cables, they could have been knocked out of adjustment, or if disconnected probably were not put back exactly.

Check out this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sheTKD03hmo) showing the adjustment procedure.